# Flutter: Items from Firestore Not Shown in the GridView until Refresh

Tags: firebase, flutter, gridview, google-cloud-firestore

I have a flutter app here connected to firestore backend and I face a strange behaviour here.

When the app starts or I do hot restart the items fetched from the database are shown for one second and then disappear again and I have to apply RefreshIndicator and drag the screen down to refresh the products and let them appear again.

Here is my code to fetch items:

```
Future<void> fetchitems() async {
  try {
    final List<Product> loadedProducts = [];

    final response = await Firestore
      .instance
      .collection("products")
      .getDocuments();

    response.documents.forEach((element) {
      loadedProducts.add(Product(
        id: element.documentID,
        title: element.data['title'],
        description: element.data['description'],
        price: element.data['price'],
        imageUrl: element.data['imageUrl']
      ));
    });

    _items = loadedProducts;
    notifyListeners();
  } catch (error) {
    print(error);
  }
}
```

Here is GridView and how it receives items:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final productsData = Provider.of<Products>(context);
    final products = productsData.items;
    return GridView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          itemCount: products.length,
          itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(

            value: products[i],
            child: ProductItem(),
          ),
```

Here is where I call the GridView:

```
class _ProductsOverviewScreenState extends State<ProductsOverviewScreen> {
  var _isIntit = true;
  var _isLoading = false;

  Future<void> _refreshProducts(BuildContext context) async {
    await Provider.of<Products>(context).fetchAndSetProducts();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (_isIntit) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
      });

      Provider.of<Products>(context).fetchitems().then((_) {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });

      });

    }
    _isIntit = false;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: _isLoading ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(), ) : RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: () => _refreshProducts(context),
        child: ProductsGrid()),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This code is not an issue, you can show how you are using _items in gridview

Comment: I added the code for the GridView and how it receives items

Answer (score 1):

```
final productsData = Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false);
```

`listen: false` ensure that build will not retrigger again in the same build.

Comment: I have tried it and set listen: false  but still facing the same problem

Comment: from where you are calling this widget, show me that code.

Comment: I added where I call it as ProductsGrid

Comment: try to remove RefreshIndicator and directly add ProductsGrid(), see if it works? then we can find some other issues.

Comment: _isLoading  is the problem, its not returning correct bool, add print statements or debug and see whats wrong

Comment: @AlexAli hey, remember to answer jitsm555's questions so we can help you further.

Comment: @jitsm555 I removed _isLoading and all the use of it from the code.. and still showing the items and disappear in a second

Comment: I added print('rebuild') before Scaffold() and found that it is printing 2 times.. I do not know why it keeps rebuilding

Comment: add listen: false to all Provider.of() uses

Comment: I made them all listen: false .. the app is running more than once in the beginning and I get this in console : "I/chatty  (10119): uid=10149(com.tasmeemy.flutterappfirestoreprovider) Thread-3 identical 1 line"

Comment: This means that my app is rebuilding 2 times in a very short time which is not supposed to be done

Comment: Do one thing add listen: false  to provider.of in your application.

Comment: I managed to get rid of items disappearing from the screen by changing the ChangeNotifier.value( value: ) in main.dart to ChangeNotifier( create: (ctx) =>)